# Is internet considered a way of broadcasting?

Tags: meaning

Wikipedia definition of Broadcasting:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting

"is the distribution of audio and/or video content or other messages to a dispersed audience via any electronic mass communications medium"

Doesn't that mean internet is a method of broadcast?

Comment: Fair warning: the answer you accepted contains incorrect information.

Comment: We are going to discuss and find an answer I hope. That's the purpose, pretty sure the OP didn't mean to be wrong deliberately if that's the case. Anyhow I have replied to your answer.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as one that is primarily opinion-based. Moreover, citing but one definition and then asking if something conforms to it, is argumentative and not really a productive way to learn English.

Comment: Cries I just wanted to know.. :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the internet is way of broadcasting, but it may be different to what traditionally was called "broadcasting".

In fact, for different devices to communicate to each other, there is specifically something call a **broadcast protocol** in the TCP/IP transport layer. All it means is that many devices can be sent messages at the same time.

Comment: There is no broadcast TCP.  There is broadcast IP (in the network layer),  but it is used for things like DHCP. That doesn't fit the original question regarding distribution of audio/video content.

Comment: I don't feel that this really answers the OP's question.  Yes, there are "broadcast protocols", but that doesn't mean "the internet is the same thing as broadcasting" as the terms are commonly understood.

Comment: @relaxing  so what you are saying is that, because the TCP/IP protocol is all individual request/response, it is not really *broadcasting* as the term is usually understood?  In other words, a radio station sends its signal out to anyone who wants to receive it, but in order to get a webpage, each individual browser has to make a unique request?

Comment: @Andrew Exactly.

Comment: @relaxing  To some extent this is splitting hairs since there are other definitions of "broadcasting" that don't specify the technology used, only the lack of targeting.  But either way it's not a question for ELL.

Comment: @Andrew I agree it's no longer an ELL question. But every dictionary I checked specifically mentions radio and television (and refers to older senses of the word not related to media distribution.)  Maybe the takeaway for ELL should be we have specific words for putting content on the internet: **webcasting, podcasting, blogging, publishing a website.**

Answer (score 1):

No. Not from a technical standpoint and not from the traditional definition of the word.

The definition you quoted continues "...typically one using the electromagnetic spectrum (radio waves), in a one-to-many model." A TV or radio broadcaster is sending out (casting) radio waves in all directions (broadly) for the listener to pick up.

The internet works in a different model. An internet site waits for readers to come to it, and retrieve information by requesting it specifically. This is why distributing messages on the internet is typically referred to as **publishing** -- the internet better fits the model of a newsstand or bookstore where information waits to be retrieved.

To add further technical detail, there is such a thing as broadcast internet traffic (one network client sending a message to all users on a network), but it is used only in special circumstances.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the term, although *webcasting* is often used.

Comment: @Mick The Wikipedia article on Webast says "Essentially, webcasting is "broadcasting" over the Internet."  I interpret the scare quotes to mean the term is nonstandard in that usage.

Comment: Yeah..But they keyword "Typically" meaning usually not often, correct? or no?

Comment: @OkamaKsakas Typically means "most commonly" or "under normal circumstances." Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

No; broadcasting requires that

> ...anyone with the appropriate receiving technology and equipment (e.g., a radio or television set) can receive the signal.
>   *(from your wikipedia page)*

The internet does not meet this definition, because it requires you to have a service provider.  You can't just fire up your computer and start getting internet content; you have to connect to a network, and that network must register you as a participant by issuing you an address, before you can access web-based information.

In a true broadcasting arrangement, it's possible that nobody doing the broadcasting would have any idea how many people listened<sup>*</sup>, because the broadcast is strictly a one-way transmission; I send, you receive.  The internet requires an active two-way connection.

---

*<sub>Of course, actual broadcasters go to great lengths to estimate the audience for their broadcasts, but they use other technologies to do so.</sub>

Comment: But it's the same thing with the internet isn't it? Service provider gives us internet and we receive. So isn't it the same thing?

Comment: If your service provider broadcasted the entire internet out at you all the time and then you just displayed the stuff you were interested in, your data usage would be insane.  :-)  Instead, as @relaxing put it in their answer, the "publishing" model fits much better: you ask for a webpage, your ISP passes the request to me, I give them the page, they pass it back to you.  The point is, you cannot get content unless you start a conversation (request/response), as opposed to simply listening.